Shader Combine Backface Cull and cull shadow
I have an unusually specific case where I want the backside of faces to be invisible to shadows as well as the camera. I got this far in getting it to cull only one side of the shadows, but I don't know if there's a way to combine these two setups to work together.


Need to filter the Backfacing visibility with the Is Camera Ray.

